# Capturar os valores de input hidden que sofreu o evento no select de "change" com serialize() do jQuery

Tags: html, ajax

O meu **AJAX** não está enviando as variáveis do formulário.

O que eu poderia fazer para pegar os valores dos campos `<input type="hidden">` com o **AJAX** no **evento change** do jQuery?

Estou fazendo assim:

**HTML form**

```
<form id="frete_<?php echo $result4["id"]?>" class="frete formAjax2" data-formid_frete="<?php echo $result4["id"]?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">           

<select class="form-control frete" name="retirar_loja" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" data-formid_loja="<?php echo $result4["id"]?>">
      <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
      <option value="pagar_retirar_loja">Pagar e Retirar na Loja</option>
      <option value="retirar_loja">Retirar na Loja</option>
    </select>


<button type="submit" name="frete" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Calcular</button>

<input  type="hidden" value="<? echo $result4['id_cliente'] ?>" id="id_cliente" name="id_cliente" class="form-control">

</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(".frete").on("change", "select", function() { 

    // Pegar o ID do formulário
    //Captura o elemento que sofreu o evento de "chancge"
    const formDetails_frete = $(this);

    var formid_loja=formDetails_frete.data("formid_loja");

    $('.resultado_frete_'+formid_loja).html('<img src="imagens/Ellipsis-1s-66px.gif">');                

    $.ajax({
    url: 'frete.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formDetails_frete.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
    // Inserting html into the result div
    $('.resultado_frete_'+formid_loja).html(data);
    $('.resultado_frete_'+formid_loja).fadeIn('slow').html(data);
        },
    error: function (xhr) {
    alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
    }

    });
```

Fiz assim no ajax também, até funcionou capturando os valores do input hidden, porém, não mostra o resultado de sucess.

```
$(".frete").on("change", "select", function() { 

    // Pegar o ID do formulário para depois:
    //Captura o elemento que sofreu o evento de "submit"
    const formDetails_frete = $(this).closest(".frete");



    var formid_loja=formDetails_frete.data("formid_loja");

    $('.resultado_frete_'+formid_loja).html('<img src="imagens/Ellipsis-1s-66px.gif">');


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'frete.php',
                    //url: '/xcommerce/public/purchastotal/'+$(this).val(),
                    type: 'POST',
                     data: formDetails_frete.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // Inserting html into the result div
            $('.resultado_frete_'+formid_loja).html(data);
            $('.resultado_frete_'+formid_loja).fadeIn('slow').html(data);
        },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
                    }
                });


        });
```

Comment: A pergunta está contraditória. No título vc diz querer pegar o elemento que sofreu o change, no corpo da pergunta vc diz querer pegar os inputs hidden.

Comment: quando sofre o change no select, teria que pegar os inputs hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está serializando apenas o select. Isso porque o select que disparou o `change` é representado pelo `$(this)` em:

```
const formDetails_frete = $(this);
```

E depois você está fazendo:

```
formDetails_frete.serialize();
```

Você deveria serializar o form todo com:

```
const formDetails_frete = $(this).closest("form");
```

O `$(this).closest("form")` irá buscar o `form` onde o select, que disparou o evento, está. Desta forma, todo o formulário, inclusive os inputs hidden, serão serializados.

É preciso alterar a linha:

```
var formid_loja=formDetails_frete.data("formid_loja");
```

Para:

```
var formid_loja=formDetails_frete.data("data-formid_frete");
```

Que é o `dataset` do form, que possui o mesmo valor do `dataset` do select.

Comment: fiz como vc falou, captura os elementos mas nao mostra o resultado do sucess do ajax, editei minha pergunta pra vc ver como fiz

Comment: Cara, aí o problema já é outro no arquivo `frete.php` que devolve alguma resposta no success.

Comment: na forma como eu fiz formDetails_frete.serialize(); aparece o resultado de sucess certinho, só não capturava os inputs hidden. Da forma que vc falou envia os inputs hidden e não mostra o resultado, rsrsrs! Estranho né?

Comment: Coloca no início do success um `console.log(data)` pare ver o que retorna.

Comment: aparece no console o resultado, pq nao aparece no site?

Comment: Adicionei mais coisas na resposta. É preciso pegar o dataset do form que possui o mesmo valor do dataset do select. Neste caso, talvez vc possa até remover o `data-formid_loja="<?php echo $result4["id"]?>"` do select.

Comment: deu certo agora, obrigadooo!